# Passing a dictionary to replace with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following dataframe:

```
                               0         1       2
0      2022-09-01T01:30:00+00:00  2543.207  -365.0
1      2022-09-01T02:00:00+00:00  2479.386  -365.0
2      2022-09-01T02:30:00+00:00  2443.331  -361.0
3      2022-09-01T03:00:00+00:00  2412.743  -360.0
4      2022-09-01T03:30:00+00:00  2398.775  -369.0
                         ...       ...     ...
18577  2023-09-24T02:00:00+00:00  2573.602  -897.0
18578  2023-09-24T02:30:00+00:00  2538.401  -915.0
18579  2023-09-24T03:00:00+00:00  2490.902  -942.0
18580  2023-09-24T03:30:00+00:00  2480.652  -959.0
18581  2023-09-24T04:00:00+00:00   199.222  -147.0
```

I want to use a replacement on the first (zeroth) column to replace "+00:00" with "" and "T" with " ", such that the following dataframe is made:

```
                         0         1          2
0      2022-09-01 01:30:00  2543.207     -365.0
1      2022-09-01 02:00:00  2479.386     -365.0
2      2022-09-01 02:30:00  2443.331     -361.0
3      2022-09-01 03:00:00  2412.743     -360.0
4      2022-09-01 03:30:00  2398.775     -369.0
                   ...       ...        ...
18577  2023-09-24 02:00:00  2573.602     -897.0
18578  2023-09-24 02:30:00  2538.401     -915.0
18579  2023-09-24 03:00:00  2490.902     -942.0
18580  2023-09-24 03:30:00  2480.652     -959.0
18581  2023-09-24 04:00:00   199.222     -147.0
```

Since I would like to reassign two different strings, I decided to use the dictionary replace method. I have tried a handful of different approaches, but none of them seem to work:

```
frame[0] = frame[0].astype('str')
frame[0] = frame[0].replace({'+00:00':'', 'T':' '})
```

```
frame[0] = frame[0].replace({'+00:00':'', 'T':' '})
```

```
frame = frame.replace({0:{"+00:00":"", "T":" "}})
```

```
frame[0] = frame[0].astype('str')
frame = frame.replace({0:{"+00:00":"", "T":" "}})
```

```
frame = frame.replace({0:{"+00:00":"", "T":" "}},regex = False)
```

None of these throw errors, but none of them work, either. They all return a carbon copy of the original dataframe. The solution that does work is:

```
frame[0] = frame[0].str.replace('T', ' ', regex = False)
frame[0] = frame[0].str.replace('+00:00','', regex = False)
```

But of course, I specifically want to know why the dictionary method is failing to work in this instance.

Comment: Convert to `datetime` and use `dt.strftime` with the desired format.

Comment: @mozway This doesn't answer my original question, which was why the dictionary replace method doesn't work if I convert it to a string. Please open my question back up again.